# Why does the position of UITableViewCellSeparator wrong?

Tags: ios, uitableview

The number of rows in section is 1;
The height for row at index path is :

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return  [LZHThreadsNoticeTableViewCell cellHeightForThreadsNotice:_myThreadsDataArray[tag-1][indexPath.row]];
}
```

the height is about 95.0f;
I custom UITableViewCell

```
LZHThreadsNoticeTableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reusableCellWithIdentifier];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[LZHThreadsNoticeTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reusableCellWithIdentifier];
    }
    [cell configureThreadsNotice:_myThreadsDataArray[tag-1][indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
```

The seperator line lies in the center of the cell
[image]

when the cell pressed it shows like below:
[image]

So why the seperator line shows in the wrong place? Thank you.

The layout subviews method is below:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews{
[_postTimeLabel sizeToFit];
_postTimeLabel.frame=CGRectMake(_viewWidth-_postTimeLabel.frame.size.width-LZHThreadsNoticeDistanceBetweenViews, LZHThreadsNoticeDistanceBetweenViews, _postTimeLabel.frame.size.width, _postTimeLabel.frame.size.height);

CGSize opticalTitleLableSize=[_titleLabel sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(_viewWidth-3*LZHThreadsNoticeDistanceBetweenViews-_postTimeLabel.frame.size.width, 9999)];
_titleLabel.frame=CGRectMake(LZHThreadsNoticeDistanceBetweenViews, LZHThreadsNoticeDistanceBetweenViews, opticalTitleLableSize.width, opticalTitleLableSize.height);

CGSize opticalMyReplyLableSize=[_myReplyLabel sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(_viewWidth-2*LZHThreadsNoticeDistanceBetweenViews, 9999)];
_myReplyLabel.frame=CGRectMake(LZHThreadsNoticeDistanceBetweenViews, _titleLabel.frame.origin.y+_titleLabel.frame.size.height+LZHThreadsNoticeDistanceBetweenViews,opticalMyReplyLableSize.width, opticalMyReplyLableSize.height);


CGSize opticalNoticeLabelSize=[_noticeLabel sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(_viewWidth-2*LZHThreadsNoticeDistanceBetweenViews, 9999)];
_noticeLabel.frame=CGRectMake(LZHThreadsNoticeDistanceBetweenViews, _myReplyLabel.frame.origin.y+_myReplyLabel.frame.size.height+LZHThreadsNoticeDistanceBetweenViews, opticalNoticeLabelSize.width, opticalNoticeLabelSize.height);

_seperatorLabel.backgroundColor=LZHThreadsNoticeSeperatorColor;
_seperatorLabel.frame=CGRectMake(LZHThreadsNoticeDistanceBetweenViews, _noticeLabel.frame.origin.y+_noticeLabel.frame.size.height+LZHThreadsNoticeDistanceBetweenViews, _viewWidth-LZHThreadsNoticeDistanceBetweenViews, 1.0f);
}
```

I have five label, from top to bottom.
And the cell height method is :

```
+(CGFloat)cellHeightForThreadsNotice:(LZHThreadsNotice *)threadsNotice{
CGFloat viewWidth=[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width;

UILabel *noticeLabel=[[UILabel alloc]init];
noticeLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:LZHThreadsNoticeSmallFontSize];
if (threadsNotice.noticeType==LZHTHreadsNoticeTypeReply) {
    noticeLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@答复您说：%@",threadsNotice.user.userName,threadsNotice.noticeContext];
}else{
    noticeLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@引用您说：%@",threadsNotice.user.userName,threadsNotice.noticeContext];
}
noticeLabel.numberOfLines=0;
noticeLabel.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
noticeLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:LZHThreadsNoticeSmallFontSize];
CGSize opticalNoticContextLableSize=[noticeLabel sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(viewWidth-2*LZHThreadsNoticeDistanceBetweenViews, 9999)];


UILabel *titleLabel=[[UILabel alloc]init];
titleLabel.text=threadsNotice.title;
titleLabel.numberOfLines=0;
titleLabel.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
titleLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:LZHThreadsNoticeBigFontSize];
UILabel *postTimeLabel=[[UILabel alloc]init];
postTimeLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:LZHThreadsNoticeSmallFontSize];
postTimeLabel.text=threadsNotice.postTime;
[postTimeLabel sizeToFit];

CGSize opticalTitleLableSize=[titleLabel sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(viewWidth-postTimeLabel.frame.size.width-3*LZHThreadsNoticeDistanceBetweenViews, 9999)];

UILabel *myReplyContextLabel=[[UILabel alloc]init];
myReplyContextLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"您的帖子：%@",threadsNotice.myReplyContext];
myReplyContextLabel.numberOfLines=0;
myReplyContextLabel.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
myReplyContextLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:LZHThreadsNoticeSmallFontSize];

CGSize opticalMyReplyContextLabelSize=[myReplyContextLabel sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(viewWidth-2*LZHThreadsNoticeDistanceBetweenViews, 9999)];

return 4*LZHThreadsNoticeDistanceBetweenViews+opticalTitleLableSize.height+opticalNoticContextLableSize.height+opticalMyReplyContextLabelSize.height+1.0f;
}
```

Comment: Do you use autolayout?

Comment: no,I only set the lable frame in layoutsubviews in the custom cell

Comment: Look at this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout

Comment: I still do not know what's wrong in my code. I cannot change the cell height , it seems it's height is always 44.0f.

Comment: paste some code wherein you show how you set the layout of TableCell and also how you calculate  the tableviewCell height ??